# On Click of an item in a recycler adapter in a fragment, display a custom popup

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity, android-context

I have a recycler view adapter inside a fragment.

On click of the items in the adapter, I want to display a custom popup.

Following is the code for the same

In **onBindViewHolder**:

```
holder.profileImageView.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {

            PopupWindow optionPopUp;

            View rootView = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.board_info_id);
            LinearLayout v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.owner_options_popup);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.owner_options_for_admin_or_user_popup, v);

            int[] location = new int[2];

            view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = location[0];
            point.y = location[1];

            // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.

            optionPopUp = new PopupWindow(context);
            optionPopUp.setContentView(layout);
            optionPopUp.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            optionPopUp.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            optionPopUp.setFocusable(true);

            //Clear the default translucent background
            optionPopUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

            // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
            optionPopUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, point.x , point.y );

            return true;
        });
```

On the line

```
View rootView = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.board_info_id);
```

I am getting the following error

cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Can anyone point out what is wrong in what I'm doing?

Comment: Pass `activity` in place of `context` in `adapter`

Comment: I am trying to display the custom view on click of a item in recycler view adapter, not in the activity

Comment: Instead of this way. create a method in Fragment and call it on button click using Fragment instance

Comment: that's because your `context` is not an Activity, but you are trying to cast it to Activity

Comment: just pass the context, from host to adapter class

Comment: actually got error because of you did not pass context from activity to adapter